Implement hard coded ssl certificate with libcurl and openssl
i have a c++ application which connects to my https authentication server. I want to prevent mitm attacks because i dont want users to be able to crack my program.
I have implemented string encryption, code obfuscation and anti debugger techniques.
This should prevent most amateur attackers for messing with my application(i guess).
But rn attackers could setup a custom DNS and create a MITM attack and modify http traffic.
My idea is to create a hard coded string which contains my server certificate or public key.
I want my application to only accept this certificate. Also the certificate shouldnt be loaded from a file because this can easily be edited.
i tried this template from libcurl documentation:
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
static size_t writefunction(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return (nmemb*size);
}
 
static CURLcode sslctx_function(CURL *curl, void *sslctx, void *parm)
{
  CURLcode rv = CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK;
 
  /** This example uses two (fake) certificates **/
  static const char mypem[] =
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "MIIH0zCCBbugAwIBAgIIXsO3pkN/pOAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwQjESMBAGA1UE\n"
    "AwwJQUNDVlJBSVoxMRAwDgYDVQQLDAdQS0lBQ0NWMQ0wCwYDVQQKDARBQ0NWMQsw\n"
    "CQYDVQQGEwJFUzAeFw0xMTA1MDUwOTM3MzdaFw0zMDEyMzEwOTM3MzdaMEIxEjAQ\n"
    "BgNVBAMMCUFDQ1ZSQUlaMTEQMA4GA1UECwwHUEtJQUNDVjENMAsGA1UECgwEQUND\n"
    "VjELMAkGA1UEBhMCRVMwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQCb\n"
    "qau/YUqXry+XZpp0X9DZlv3P4uRm7x8fRzPCRKPfmt4ftVTdFXxpNRFvu8gMjmoY\n"
    "HtiP2Ra8EEg2XPBjs5BaXCQ316PWywlxufEBcoSwfdtNgM3802/J+Nq2DoLSRYWo\n"
    "G2ioPej0RGy9ocLLA76MPhMAhN9KSMDjIgro6TenGEyxCQ0jVn8ETdkXhBilyNpA\n"
    "0KIV9VMJcRz/RROE5iZe+OCIHAr8Fraocwa48GOEAqDGWuzndN9wrqODJerWx5eH\n"
    "k6fGioozl2A3ED6XPm4pFdahD9GILBKfb6qkxkLrQaLjlUPTAYVtjrs78yM2x/47\n"
    "JyCpZET/LtZ1qmxNYEAZSUNUY9rizLpm5U9EelvZaoErQNV/+QEnWCzI7UiRfD+m\n"
    "AM/EKXMRNt6GGT6d7hmKG9Ww7Y49nCrADdg9ZuM8Db3VlFzi4qc1GwQA9j9ajepD\n"
    "vV+JHanBsMyZ4k0ACtrJJ1vnE5Bc5PUzolVt3OAJTS+xJlsndQAJxGJ3KQhfnlms\n"
    "tn6tn1QwIgPBHnFk/vk4CpYY3QIUrCPLBhwepH2NDd4nQeit2hW3sCPdK6jT2iWH\n"
    "7ehVRE2I9DZ+hJp4rPcOVkkO1jMl1oRQQmwgEh0q1b688nCBpHBgvgW1m54ERL5h\n"
    "I6zppSSMEYCUWqKiuUnSwdzRp+0xESyeGabu4VXhwOrPDYTkF7eifKXeVSUG7szA\n"
    "h1xA2syVP1XgNce4hL60Xc16gwFy7ofmXx2utYXGJt/mwZrpHgJHnyqobalbz+xF\n"
    "d3+YJ5oyXSrjhO7FmGYvliAd3djDJ9ew+f7Zfc3Qn48LFFhRny+Lwzgt3uiP1o2H\n"
    "pPVWQxaZLPSkVrQ0uGE3ycJYgBugl6H8WY3pEfbRD0tVNEYqi4Y7\n"
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "MIIFtTCCA52gAwIBAgIIYY3HhjsBggUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwRDEWMBQGA1UE\n"
    "AwwNQUNFRElDT00gUm9vdDEMMAoGA1UECwwDUEtJMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZFRElDT00x\n"
    "CzAJBgNVBAYTAkVTMB4XDTA4MDQxODE2MjQyMloXDTI4MDQxMzE2MjQyMlowRDEW\n"
    "MBQGA1UEAwwNQUNFRElDT00gUm9vdDEMMAoGA1UECwwDUEtJMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZF\n"
    "RElDT00xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkVTMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKC\n"
    "AgEA/5KV4WgGdrQsyFhIyv2AVClVYyT/kGWbEHV7w2rbYgIB8hiGtXxaOLHkWLn7\n"
    "09gtn70yN78sFW2+tfQh0hOR2QetAQXW8713zl9CgQr5auODAKgrLlUTY4HKRxx7\n"
    "XBZXehuDYAQ6PmXDzQHe3qTWDLqO3tkE7hdWIpuPY/1NFgu3e3eM+SW10W2ZEi5P\n"
    "gvoFNTPhNahXwOf9jU8/kzJPeGYDdwdY6ZXIfj7QeQCM8htRM5u8lOk6e25SLTKe\n"
    "I6RF+7YuE7CLGLHdztUdp0J/Vb77W7tH1PwkzQSulgUV1qzOMPPKC8W64iLgpq0i\n"
    "5ALudBF/TP94HTXa5gI06xgSYXcGCRZj6hitoocf8seACQl1ThCojz2GuHURwCRi\n"
    "ipZ7SkXp7FnFvmuD5uHorLUwHv4FB4D54SMNUI8FmP8sX+g7tq3PgbUhh8oIKiMn\n"
    "MCArz+2UW6yyetLHKKGKC5tNSixthT8Jcjxn4tncB7rrZXtaAWPWkFtPF2Y9fwsZ\n"
    "o5NjEFIqnxQWWOLcpfShFosOkYuByptZ+thrkQdlVV9SH686+5DdaaVbnG0OLLb6\n"
    "zqylfDJKZ0DcMDQj3dcEI2bw/FWAp/tmGYI1Z2JwOV5vx+qQQEQIHriy1tvuWacN\n"
    "GHk0vFQYXlPKNFHtRQrmjseCNj6nOGOpMCwXEGCSn1WHElkQwg9naRHMTh5+Spqt\n"
    "r0CodaxWkHS4oJyleW/c6RrIaQXpuvoDs3zk4E7Czp3otkYNbn5XOmeUwssfnHdK\n"
    "Z05phkOTOPu220+DkdRgfks+KzgHVZhepA==\n"
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
 
  BIO *cbio = BIO_new_mem_buf(mypem, sizeof(mypem));
  X509_STORE  *cts = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store((SSL_CTX *)sslctx);
  int i;
  STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *inf;
  (void)curl;
  (void)parm;
 
  if(!cts || !cbio) {
    return rv;
  }
 
  inf = PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(cbio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
  if(!inf) {
    BIO_free(cbio);
    return rv;
  }
 
  for(i = 0; i < sk_X509_INFO_num(inf); i++) {
    X509_INFO *itmp = sk_X509_INFO_value(inf, i);
    if(itmp->x509) {
      X509_STORE_add_cert(cts, itmp->x509);
    }
    if(itmp->crl) {
      X509_STORE_add_crl(cts, itmp->crl);
    }
  }
 
  sk_X509_INFO_pop_free(inf, X509_INFO_free);
  BIO_free(cbio);
 
  rv = CURLE_OK;
  return rv;
}
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *ch;
  CURLcode rv;
 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  ch = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunction);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, writefunction);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, stderr);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/");
 
  /* Turn off the default CA locations, otherwise libcurl loads CA
   * certificates from the locations that were detected/specified at
   * build-time
   */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL);
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL);
 
  /* first try: retrieve page without ca certificates -> should fail
   * unless libcurl was built --with-ca-fallback enabled at build-time
   */
  rv = curl_easy_perform(ch);
  if(rv == CURLE_OK)
    printf("*** transfer succeeded ***\n");
  else
    printf("*** transfer failed ***\n");
 
  /* use a fresh connection (optional) this option seriously impacts
   * performance of multiple transfers but it is necessary order to
   * demonstrate this example. recall that the ssl ctx callback is only called
   * _before_ an SSL connection is established, therefore it does not affect
   * existing verified SSL connections already in the connection cache
   * associated with this handle. normally you would set the ssl ctx function
   * before making any transfers, and not use this option.
   */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1L);
 
  /* second try: retrieve page using cacerts' certificate -> succeeds to load
   * the certificate by installing a function doing the necessary
   * "modifications" to the SSL CONTEXT just before link init
   */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, sslctx_function);
  rv = curl_easy_perform(ch);
  if(rv == CURLE_OK)
    printf("*** transfer succeeded ***\n");
  else
    printf("*** transfer failed ***\n");
 
  curl_easy_cleanup(ch);
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return rv;
}

but no matter what ssl key i insert into the string it will just successfully connect to the server, which is not the intended behaviour. i want to "whitelist" the hard coded certificate.

Have you considered CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY as an alternative? For your code, though, is it possible the SSL context's X509_STORE already has certificates? If you use X509_STORE_new and then set it for the context instead of using the context's existing one does behavior change? And do the X509_STORE_ calls return success (1), or are they possibly failing?

thank you very much, i just figured that out myself.  im just using CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY  now
